# Signing an API Key (bittrex api) [NODE]

Tags: node.js, api, signed

so I am trying to make an API call to bittrex. It seems it requires me to sign the api key.

I have

```
export const account_balance_for_currency = (currency) =>
    `https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalance?apikey=${signedKey}&currency=${currency}&nonce=${nonce()}`;
```

Now I have my key on `process.env` and secret on `process.env`

Tried to do

```
const signedKey = crypto
    .createHmac('sha512', `${process.env.BITTREX_SECRET}`)
    .update(`${process.env.BITTREX_API_KEY}`)
    .digest('hex');
```

But it doesn't work and I haven't found a great way to just do it as I want to.

I keep getting `success: false, message: 'APISIGN_NOT_PROVIDED'`

Any advice / solutions? I don't want to use the existing `npm` packages for the api as this is really the only missing piece.

Answer (score 1):

You must sign the entire API call, not the API key.

```
const Crypto = require('crypto');
const account_balance_for_currency = `https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalance?apikey=${process.env.BITTREX_API_KEY}&currency=${currency}&nonce=${nonce()}`;
const signature = Crypto.createHmac('sha512', process.env.BITTREX_SECRET)
  .update(account_balance_for_currency)
  .digest('hex');
```

You can then send the full request using an HTTP client like axios. Bittrex requires the signature in the `apisign` header of the request.

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: account_balance_for_currency,
  headers: {
    apisign: signature
  }
})
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```